# Firebase: How to create Firestore real time updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was thinking of implementing a logic for my modal which will make real time updates to my db but couldn't manage to find out how.

Current code:

```
 const handleUpdateUserData = async () => {
    const userRef = doc(db, "users", currentUserUid);

    await updateDoc(userRef, {
      name: name,
      bio: bio,
    });
    updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
      displayName: name,
    });
  };
```

currently user can input other values and then the db updates after save click. Probably i can leave that as it's now but also i would like to see other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to a specific document in realtime using the snapshot function:

```js
const ref = doc(db, "users", currentUserUid)
onSnapshot(ref, {
    next: (data) => { ... }
})
```

You can update that same reference in response to a UI event:

```html
<input type="text" oninput="updateDb(this.value)" />
<button>Save</button>
```

```js
updateDb(usrInput) {
  const ref = doc(db, "users", currentUserUid)
  await updateDoc(ref, {
    fieldName: userInput
  });
}
```

Comment: please provide an example of its usage

Comment: What more are you looking for?

Comment: just a small code example with input, functions and probably you know similar approach but with storage